# Easy way to switch scylla cluster to large aws instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, scylla

I have a scylla cluster running on AWS `i3en.xlarge` instances which has 16 nodes.

Is there an easy way for me to switch the cluster to `i3en.2xlarge` or `i3en.4xlarge` other than replacing existing node one by one (e.g. add a new node and remove a node)?

If I add one i3en.2xlarge instance, will the cluster auto balances the data so that on the `i3en.2xlarge` it uses roughly twice the disk space as `i3en.xlarge`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a new DC with the desired instance type (see the procedure @TzachLivyatan posted in his comment)
2. Wait for streaming to the new DC to complete
3. Run a full cluster repair -> wait for it to complete
4. Decommission the "original" DC:
   https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cluster-management/decommissioning_data_center/

Answer (score 7):

You can add a logical DC of the new nodes, run repair and then get rid of the original DC

Comment: Adding a New Data Center Into an Existing Scylla Cluster https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cluster-management/add_dc_to_exist_dc/